# A song "by" a singer or "from" a singer or "of" a singer

Tags: word-usage

For example, I want to recommend a song of Adele to my friend. Should I say:
The Someone Like You by Adele is fantastic.
or
The Someone Like You from Adele is fantastic.
or
The Someone Like You of Adele is fantastic.
or something else.

Comment: Hello Miles, both prepositions can be used but the meaning won't be the same.

Comment: Yes.  Say something more.  "Sung by Adele" ... "Written by Adele" ... "Videoed by Adele" ... "Named for Adele" ... "Inspired by Adele".

Comment: Well, you can knock one of them off the list. "The Someone Like You **of** Adele" just sounds horribly awkward to the ear.

Comment: @Souta: You are right, of course, but, oddly enough, there are times when _of_ **is** the right preposition, like: "Music of the 60s" or "Best of Fleetwood Mac".

Comment: @J.R. I wasn't speaking of those instances. I was speaking of the current one, and only of the current one. And that usage of `of` is different in comparison to OP's question.

Comment: @Souta: That's why I said you were right :^) And I agree that the usage is not the same, but it is similar. My point was to show how the "right" answer in these cases can shift with just a slight change in context.

Comment: Note there's also "featuring", where "a song by X, feat. Y" means it's Y who's singing, but X was the author or the original creator.

Comment: @J.R. ^-^ I should have figured that one; apologies.

Comment: @SF: That phrasing is also used when Y is a featured artist on a song on X's album (e.g., _Money for Nothing_ by Dire Straits feat. Sting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Someone Like You* by Adele is fantastic.
>
> *Someone Like You* from Adele is fantastic.
>
> *Someone Like You* of Adele is fantastic.

I would say that the first is the standard usage and most correct.

The second is not wrong, but it sounds a bit colloquial to me.

The third is incorrect English. With people, you say "of Adele**'s**" with a possessive **'s**. It means it's *her song*, rather than *a song by her*, if that makes sense.

Comment: Regarding the last point, not probably, but most certainly. *The* is not part of the song's title, so "Adele's the" is plain ungrammatical, much like "My the car" or "My sister's the picture". Possessives and articles don't mix like that.

Comment: @Gulliver Thank you. But what's the difference between "a song by her" and "her song"? I still don't get it.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. As I see it:

With "a song by her", the focus is on "a song", that happens to be a song by Adele. 

With "Adele's song", the focus is on Adele *and* her song. 

I would probably use "Adele's Someone Like You" at the beginning of a sentence, introducing a new topic, but "Someone Like You by Adele" towards the end of a sentence, when it's just clarifying *which* song by *which artist*. 

I think. Sorry, that's very vague and I'm sure someone else can give a better answer.

Comment: Thank you. "I would probably use "Adele's Someone Like You" at the beginning of a sentence, introducing a new topic, but "Someone Like You by Adele" towards the end of a sentence, when it's just clarifying which song by which artist." I think I get it.